# shortcut for scheduled task not working

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, shortcut

In my Windows 10 Task Scheduler Library I have a folder called UAC BYPASS.  In that folder I have a task call Cmder. If I right click on that task it runs a s expected.  I've created a shortcut with this target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /RUN/TN "UAC BYPASS\Cmder"
```

However when double clicked it doesn't run

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /Run /TN  "UAC BYPASS\cmder"